# Web application's response time increases during execution of automated scripts

Tags: c#, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have following issues with Coded ui automation:
1. Web application's response time increases during execution of automated scripts. 
2. Even controls become invisible but the execution continues.

If I open the application manually it opens within no time.
Configuration : Windows server 2012 R2, IE11, Visual studio 2015, Coded ui with c#.

Does anybody know how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I used PlayBack class to improve performance.
Here is the [Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2012/01/31/guidelines-on-improving-performance-of-coded-ui-test-playback/) which helped me a lot.

1. Make use of Playback.Settings
2. Use Container to limit your search to find control faster.
3. Make sure to clear cookies and close all the IE windows before starting the test. Use BrowserWindow class for that.
4. Add the website you are testing to trusted site and enable scripting from Internet OPtions > Security > trusted sites > custom level > Scripting  > Active scripting - enable

Also you can go through [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mathew_aniyan/2011/02/28/smart-match-slow-coded-ui-tests/) blog as well, if it helps.